# Is it possible to set token to authorize Specific APIs while allowing access to other?

Tags: authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to set token to authorize Specific APIs while not allowing access to other? or is the authorization global if you have a token.
For example, i have two controllers in my .net core API
each has multiple APIs exposed.

when a user logs in, is it possible to issue a token that allows user to only use APIs in controller1 and not use any in controller 2 and vice versa??

Comment: You can try to add and use a specific claim info in token, then specify and apply different authorization policies to controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds the same as authorization.
My way is that I add the **roleId** to the **claim** of the token, after that, I custom the **Authorization Attribute** (refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to verify a user can or can't access the controller.